# Where is the highest Bungee jump above sea?

Tags: factoids, where-on-earth, water-sports, extreme-sports

I want to know, Where is the highest Bungee jump above sea?

Comment: A question for [outdoors SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Outdoors.SE claims to be about "outdoor activities, excursions, and outdoorsmanship" and currently has no posts about bungee jumping. So maybe ask on their meta site before migrating.

Comment: By above sea, do you just mean above water?

Comment: I think another clarification is needed: is "by the sea" included in your question or you mean strictly over the sea?

Comment: Rent a helicopter and have it fly as high as possible, then jump.

Comment: Of course I meant "above sea" because I heared it's in Dalian China but not really sure so to confirm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The highest jump is at the Macau tower, at 233m, but it's technically a controlled descent, not a true bungee.   That's the Skyjump. They do however, have a bungee with a guide rope there too.  However, it's not over sea or water, as you requested.

So then you have to look at the jump from the top of the Verzasca Dam near Locarno, Switzerland. It appears in the opening scene of the James Bond film GoldenEye, and is 220m high!

The Bloukrans Bridge Bungy has been operated by Face Adrenalin commercially since 1997 and uses a pendulum bungee system. It is 216m high, from the platform to the river below. So if you're wanting one over water, that would qualify as the true highest, and indeed is the highest bridge jump in the world.

However, if you're wanting one over the sea as in ocean (so not river), then you're going to be looking at the 150m jump in Helsinki, Finland.

Source: [Wikipedia article on Bungee jumping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bungee_jumping#The_highest_jump) and [CNN article on top 15 highest bungee jumps](http://travel.cnn.com/explorations/life/worlds-15-highest-bungee-jumping-sites-479316).

Comment: Can't one jump from an (almost) arbitrarily high flying helicopter?

Comment: @gerrit that wouldn't be what he asked then. Given he's asking where the highest is, he's referring to a object that he can travel to, rather than how to do the highest bungee.  However, if indeed he was asking how to do the highest, a giant rope from a helicopter would do it.

Comment: Not just any giant rope from a helicopter would do it. I believe there are proper accredited places that can take you for a helicopter bungee though.

Comment: @hippietrail or balloon.

Answer (score 7):

According to this list: http://travel.cnn.com/explorations/life/worlds-15-highest-bungee-jumping-sites-479316

and crossing it with the description here: http://www.skybreakers.com/eng/suomenkorkein_eng.htm

apparently the highest bungee jump above/over the sea is in Kaivopuisto, Helsinki, Finland. The jump is done from 150 mts high.

It's very likely that other jumps over the sea, from higher heights, have been done. This is the highest commercial one (commercial in the sense - schedule or arrive, pay, do!).

[image: bungee jump over the sea]

Answer (score -3):

This is Dalian's Bungee jump (Dalian China). I heard from people that it's the highest above the sea. I couldn't find its exact height on Google.

[image: Dalian bungee jump]

Comment: Per this Baidu Baike page, it's only 55 meters high. "公园内的游乐项目很多，有从新西兰引进的世界最豪华的海上蹦极跳，跳台高55米。"http://baike.baidu.com/view/55366.htm#refIndex_2_55366